# Swift 4 - Insert a new rows from array to section with only one static row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My tableView at start have n section. Every section have only one row but every row contains button which add to section rows from array.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    let postModel = self.postsArray[section];

    if (self.currentSection == section)
    {
        return 1 + (postModel.comments?.count)!;
    }
    else
    {
        print("nie rozszerzone")

        return 1;
    }
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return self.postsArray.count;
}
```

I tried to do this this way

```
func showComments(model: MGPostModel, sender: MGCommunityPostTableViewCell)
{
    guard let path = self.communityTableView.indexPath(for: sender) else {
        return;
    }

    print(path)
    print(model.comments?.count as Any)

    self.currentSection = path.section;
    //model.comments.count is equal 3
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: (model.comments?.count)!, section: path.section);

    print(indexPath)

    self.communityTableView.beginUpdates();
    self.communityTableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic);
    self.communityTableView.endUpdates();

    //self.communityTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic);
}
```

But the response is "Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (4) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted)..."

I know that numberOfRows expected 4 rows but why insertRows try to insert only one when should insert 3 rows?

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:-** You must have to update data of number of rows which is use in tableview method. Ex->myarray.count

postModel.comments?.count --> Update it before insert a row.

**Step 2:-** Once your rows count data updated you can go for update, add or delete rows or tableview reload.

**Note: In your code no any data update which is use to declare number of rows in tableview.**

Answer (score 0):

you have to update your date source before modify table operation (delet,inser,move)

before this line

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: (model.comments?.count)!, section: path.section);
```

write this , inserting new element

```
model.comment.append(newelement)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Abdelahad Darwish, @Rakesh Patelyes, I know this but.

Row with index 0 is postModel which contains array named comment. I don't want to add postModel to comment array.

Should look like this:

Section 0:

- Row 0 - Post model
- Row 1 - comment[0]
- Row n = comment[n]

So if I add something to postModel.comment it will destroy this hierarchy.